# Extendable database schema for contacts (social)

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have an old application that needs upgrading. Doesn't everything now days?

The existing DB schema consists of predefined fields like phone, fax, email. Obviously with the social explosion over the last 5-7 years (or longer depending on your country) end users need more control over creating contact cards the way they see fit rather than just what I think might be useful.

Im concerned here with "digital" addresses. i.e. One line type addresses. phone=ccc ccc ccc ccc etc
Since physical addresses are pretty standard in terms of requirements in this case users will have to use what they are given (location, postal, delivery) in order to keep the scope managable.

So I'm wondering what the best practice format for storing digital info is. To me it seems I have two choices:

1. A simple 4 field table (ContactId, AddressTypeId, Address, FormatterId)

> 1000, "phone", "ccc ccc ccc ccc", phoneformatter
>
> 1000, "facebook", "myfacebook", facebookformatter

This would then be JOINED anywhere it's need. The table would get massive though and the join performance would degrade over time i suspect.

1. A json blob that would require additional processing once read (ContactId, Addresses)

> 1000, {{"phone": "ccc ccc ccc ccc"}, {"facebook": "myfacebook"}}

Or ... something else.

This db is for use in a given country by customers only trading domestically with client bases ranging from 3000-12000 accounts and then however many contacts per account - averages about 10 in current system.

My primary concern is user flexibility but performance is a key consideration in that. So I dunno, just do whatever and throw heaps of hardware at it ;)

Application is in C# if that makes any difference re: post query processing.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sql Server all the way.

Comment: Given the small number of records, and the flexible set of attributes ("address-types"), the natural choice would be some  kind of EAV-model, (like the one in the first fragment)

Comment: Storing the attributes in json (or XML) is a terrible idea since it violates 2NF. In fact you are building and maintaining a set of columns inside a column. (what the OP calls *extra effort* in a comment on the answer by @codeomnitrix )

Comment: @wildplasser +1 for EAV-model. Never heard of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not go for the JSON blob.  This will be nasty if you need to answer any queries like:-

- Does anyone have me in their Facebook contacts?
- What's the most popular type of social media contact?

You would be forced to parse the JSON for every record and be unable to create a simple index.

Your additional solution is nearly correct, however FormatterId would need to be on a AddressType table.   What you have is not normalised as FormatterId would depend only on AddressTypeId.  So you would have three tables:-

- Contact
- ContactAddress
- AddressType

You haven't stated if you need to store two addresses of the same type against a single contact. e.g. if someone has two twitter accounts.  Answering this question will allow you to define the correct primary key on ContactAddress.  It would either be (ContactId, AddressTypeId) if you can only have one of each type per contact or create a synthenic key (ContactAddressId).

Comment: I thought that with the jSon I could use some full text query (Sql Server) to pull answers to your bullet point questions. Since the text format would be fairly well understood, I thought I might able to craft something that works nicely... tho I never have. Also looking at shifting whole data layer to EF.... Does that affect your answer in anyway? Two of the same sounds is a reasonable use case really depends on the user prefs, I don't see why I shouldn't build in support for that, it's hardly any extra effort.

Comment: It's still a bad idea to use the JSON in my opinion.  I have a similar column (except it's XML) and it's painful to query and update.  It's easy to create bad data as there are no constraints enforced by the database.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I believe you have a table named contact

`contact(contactid, contact details, other details)`

and now you want to remove this contact details from the contact table because the contact details may contain digital address, phone number and all.

But the table you are considering

`(ContactId, AddressTypeId, Address, FormatterId)` is not in normal form and you can't uniquely identify a tuple until you read all the four columns which is bad and in this case indexing also not going to help you.

So better if you have if separate table for each type of the digital address, and have indexing on contactID

```
facebookdetails(contactid, rest of the details)
phonedetails(contactid, rest of the details)
```

And then the query can be join of all the tables, it will not degrade the performance.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Sorry but that's a terrible idea. Then instead of field explosion i would have table explosion.. the nature of the question is in not knowing how many different types of social/digital addresses the user wishes to store. So i couldn't possibly create a table per address "type" Using the first method i outlined only requires using two field to a particular address contactid and addresstype though typically id be returning a result set > 1 anyway.